# Python:Change pip path

Tags: python

I install py3.6 in dir *A* but later I install py3.7 in dir *B*. But I prefer to use py3.7 so I replace the whole dir *A* with dir *B*(*A* is filled with py3.7 and *B* does not exist anymore).
Now, my pip is using path:*B* but it does not exist anymore so I need to change it.
***HELP!***

**Edit:**

I use

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
```

and install it again with easy_install 
***BUT*** now it said something cannot *import main*

Answer (score 2):

**Answer For Windows:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then replace the old path with the new one at the new one:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable:

`PIP_TARGET=/path/to/pip/dir`

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables

Comment: Where from? Where does this "PIP_TARGER" thing exist?

Comment: The environment variable is a concatenation of the prefix `PIP_` and the CLI option (in uppercase, dashes replaced with underscores). For example, the `--target` option (used with `pip install`) in environment variable form is `PIP_TARGET`.